# can not resolve getboolean in sharedpreference

Tags: android

I want to use sharedpreferrences in android. I put data to it but when get data in other activity, it can not find prefs.getboolean.

```
class A{
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("keymode", 0).edit();
   editor.putBoolean("BotKey", true);
   editor.commit();}
class B{
  SharedPreferences prefs = ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("keymode", 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
  if(prefs.getBoolean("BotKey",false)){}
  }
```

Comment: Just copy pasted your code into IDE and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: thank you but dose not work it.

Comment: Are you putting this code in methods?  As written this won't compile because you have statements that aren't in a method.

Comment: I used it in OnCreate methode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use that way:

To store values in shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("BotKey", true);
editor.apply();
```

To retrieve values from shared preferences:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean isBotKey = preferences.getBoolean("BotKey", false);
```

Like Ziem said on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027631/5090511

Comment: in if statement for name there is this error:"Unknown class'name'"

Comment: Tom, can you post your all class? And the full exception error trace?

Comment: I solved it, thank you.

Comment: My answer helped you?

Comment: Of course and send +1 for you.